# Extract jms text content

Tags: java, jms, message-queue

I want to extract only jms message text without headers and properties from jms message.
To extract JMS header :`msg.getJMSCorrelationID()`;
To extract JMS properties:`jmsMessage.getPropertyNames()`
But how to get only the text value from the message?
In the below sample message I want to extract only "**hello queue**".Is there a java function to do this?
[image: jms message sample]

Comment: Just call msg.getText()

Comment: @Rad4 Was the below answer useful. If so would appreciate your vote. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If the message body is a text message (Plain text or XML), it can be extracted like the following.

```
String msgBody = ((TextMessage) message).getText();
```

The JMS 2.0 API exposes the additional method `<T> T getBody(Class<T> c)` in the `Message` interface.

If your Message broker or the source is JMS 2.0 compliant, then we extract the message body in a much more clean way without object cast as follows.

```
String msgBody = message.getBody(String.class);
```

Check out the [this post](http://muralitechblog.com/how-to-extract-text-content-from-jms-message/) for more details.

Comment: I got this working msg.getText() .Thanks to  @user3714601 also.

Comment: Good to hear.. If your Broker is JMS 2.0 complaint, you can use the new way too. Pls accept the answer if useful..

Comment: http://muralitechblog.com/how-to-extract-text-content-from-jms-message/

Comment: The first solution worked for me before (I'm using AMQ broker that supports JMS 1.1), but now it throws this error at runtime before even receiving any messages: 

`java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQBytesMessage cannot be cast to class javax.jms.TextMessage`

Comment: @dko You may need to use instanceof to see which hierarchy your JMS message belongs to. There are several, common ones being BytesMessage and TextMessage.